# Какие пакеты api android и java совпадают полность?

Tags: java, android, api

Где можно узнать какие пакеты полностью совпадают в Java 8 и Android 4.x и выше? Какие пакеты совпадают полностью? Например java.awt.* насколько я помню совпадает не до конца и такие пакеты предлагать не надо.

UPD. «Ребята из Google также пересмотрели стандартные пакеты Java JDK API. Они удалили некоторые из них (например всё, что касалось Swing) и добавили некоторое количество собственных — их имя начинается с «android».»
©https://habrahabr.ru/post/140459/

Comment: а зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: У меня есть библиотека на java SE, хочу портировать на андроид и заранее знать, какие классы надо переписывать.

Comment: она у вас в исходных кодах? какое назначение у библиотеки?

Comment: Да, библиотека в исходных кодах, написана на java 8.

Comment: какое назначение у библиотеки?

Comment: Библиотека преобразует одни данные в другие. Библиотека не графическая и не звуковая.